# GLES 2.0 draws GL_POINTS as squares on Android?

Tags: qt, opengl-es-2.0, qt5

Below is a simple QT program using a VBO to draw 6 points.  The points appear as squares on Android and single pixels on the desktop.  When I change `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader, the squares change to the appropriate size on Android but remain single pixels on the desktop.

example.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets opengl

TARGET = example
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES = main.cpp
HEADERS = main.h
```

main.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QGLShader>

class glview : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit glview(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    quint32 vbo_id[1];
    QGLShaderProgram *program;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "main.h"

struct vrtx {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
}__attribute__((packed)) geomrtry[] = {
    //   x, y, z   r, g, b
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1.5, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
    {3.5, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    {4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    glview widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}

glview::glview(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void glview::initializeGL()
{
    initializeGLFunctions();
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);

    QGLShader *vshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex, this);
    const char *vsrc =
        "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
        "attribute mediump vec4 colour;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 f_colour;\n"
        "uniform mediump mat4 matrix;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
        "    f_colour = colour;\n"
        "    gl_PointSize = 12.0;\n"
        "}\n";
    vshader->compileSourceCode(vsrc);

    QGLShader *fshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment, this);
    const char *fsrc =
        "varying mediump vec4 f_colour;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = f_colour;\n"
        "}\n";
    fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc);

    program = new QGLShaderProgram(this);
    program->addShader(vshader);
    program->addShader(fshader);
    program->link();

    glGenBuffers(1, vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(geomrtry), geomrtry, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void glview::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void glview::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.ortho(0, 5, 0, 3, -1, 1);

    program->bind();
    program->setUniformValue("matrix", matrix);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    int vertexLocation = program->attributeLocation("vertex");
    program->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct vrtx), 0);

    int colourLocation = program->attributeLocation("colour");
    program->enableAttributeArray(colourLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colourLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 12));

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(geomrtry) / sizeof(struct vrtx));
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, sizeof(geomrtry) / sizeof(struct vrtx));

    glFlush();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using functionality where the size of rendered points is taken from a built-in `gl_PointSize` variable set in the vertex shader. This functionality is the default in ES 2.0.

The same functionality is available in desktop OpenGL as well, but it is disabled by default. It can be enabled by calling:

```
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

If this setting is not enabled, desktop OpenGL uses the point size set with the `glPointSize()` API call.

Comment: After enabling GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE the desktop now obeys gl_PointSize in the vertex shader, thank you.  Is glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS) supposed to draw solid squares or solid circles?

Comment: Yes, based on what I saw in the specs, it sounded like points are always square. That's true at least for modern OpenGL variations (ES, and core profile on deskop). If you want non-square dots, you have to implement that in the fragment shader. Legacy OpenGL had features (`GL_POINT_SMOOTH`) that I think supported round points.